# Create users with only view privileges in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Is it possible in postgres to create roles with privileges on the views only?
The role should only be able to see the views and retrieve data from those?

I know this is doable in oracle, but did not find a way to do it in postgres.

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: As @a_horse_with_no_name pointed out [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102262/postgresql-a-login-role-to-only-access-views) thats not so trivial..

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. I was aware of that solution but hoped that it would maybe be possible to avoid creating an additional schema for that purpose.